# How do you make the items in a JList toggle when you click them?

Tags: java, swing, toggle, jlist

I currently have a JList and I need the items to be able to be toggled with a single click, similarly to how Ctrl-click works when it is set to `MULTIPLE_INTERVAL` for the selection mode.

Is it possible to make the items select and deselect as follows if there are items A, B and C without making the user require Ctrl-click?

-The user clicks A, A is selected

-The user clicks B, A and B are selected

-The user clicks A, B is selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I can think to do this is to add a `MouseListener` and capture the clicks and manually select/unselect items.

Comment: Nevermind, I found an example with a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528344/jlist-deselect-when-clicking-an-already-selected-item