# Make JList behave on click the same way as on ctrl+click?

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I'm looking for a way to make a `JList` always toggle the selection for the clicked item without deselecting the others, the same way as <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>click</kbd> works.

The [`ListSelectionModel`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListSelectionModel.html) seems to be the right way to go but I can't figure out what has to be configured in there.

How to make a JList behave on <kbd>click</kbd> the same way as on <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>click</kbd>?

Comment: See my answer to a related question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528344/jlist-deselect-when-clicking-an-already-selected-item/9196431#9196431

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to make your own ListSelectionModel. try it.

```
list.setSelectionModel(new DefaultListSelectionModel() 
{
    @Override
    public void setSelectionInterval(int index0, int index1) 
    {
        if(list.isSelectedIndex(index0)) 
        {
            list.removeSelectionInterval(index0, index1);
        }
        else 
        {
            list.addSelectionInterval(index0, index1);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: That's the piece of code I've often found, but it only adds toggling if clicking on the selected item

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following `ListSelectionModel`:

```
list.setSelectionModel(new DefaultListSelectionModel(){
    @Override
    public void setSelectionInterval(int start, int end) {
        if (start != end) {
            super.setSelectionInterval(start, end);
        } else if (isSelectedIndex(start)) {
            removeSelectionInterval(start, end);
        } else {
            addSelectionInterval(start, end);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks!! I've been searching the web for a while for this one

Answer (score 2):

maybe this code can do that correctly

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Ctrl_Down_JList {

    private static void createAndShowUI() {
        String[] items = {"Sun", "Mon", "Tues", "Wed", "Thurs", "Fri", "Sat"};
        JList myJList = new JList(items) {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            protected void processMouseEvent(MouseEvent e) {
                int modifiers = e.getModifiers() | InputEvent.CTRL_MASK;
                // change the modifiers to believe that control key is down
                int modifiersEx = e.getModifiersEx() | InputEvent.CTRL_MASK;
                // can I use this anywhere?  I don't see how to change the modifiersEx of the MouseEvent
                MouseEvent myME = new MouseEvent((Component) e.getSource(), e.getID(), e.getWhen(), modifiers, e.getX(),
                        e.getY(), e.getXOnScreen(), e.getYOnScreen(), e.getClickCount(), e.isPopupTrigger(), e.getButton());
                super.processMouseEvent(myME);
            }
        };
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Ctrl_Down_JList");
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(myJList));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, that might have worked. I'll keep that in mind if I require to fake a key sometime :)