# How to add a custom checkbox into JList (Java)?

Tags: java, checkbox, jlist

This is how the program looks:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOFCh.png]

This is how I want it to look:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTdlJ.png]

As you can see in the picture I have tried a bit and learned that I need to use `ListCellRenderer`, but the problem is i have created 2 custom png files

1. checked.png and
2. unchecked.png

when I click daily `goals #1` it should give `state = true` and `checked.png` should appear and stay checked unless I click it again. `Unchecked.png` could be standard on the `jList column`.

I also want to place my checkbox 1 cm to the left of the end of the row (padding) not sure hows its done in java sadly. (You'll understand better by looking at the picture)

After looking through some guides I have learned that the only way to add extra stuff to a `JList column` is by using `ListCellRenderer`. I have tried quite a while with no success so thought of asking others. Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

The thought was to get it to work then display in a JTable by changing the Jtable column to Daily goals and displaying X to indicate the goal was achieved. But I think I should be able to do this, The main question is the custom checkbox implementation.

Comment: I think a JButton would be better if you wan't something like than.

Comment: Can you show what you tried with `ListCellRenderer`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can have two types of checkboxes to be used as jlist cell renderers, one for selected cells, another for unselected.
2. Use ImageIcon to decorate the checkbox with your images.
3. In your jlist cell render you need to have logic to return the intended checkbox to render that list cell.
4. Note to override the text in the checkbox to the actual list cell value

   ```
   public class TestFrame extends JFrame {
   ImageIcon iconChecked = new ImageIcon(TestFrame.class.getResource("checked.png"));
   ImageIcon iconUnchecked = new ImageIcon(TestFrame.class.getResource("unchecked.png"));
   JList jList = new JList(new Object[]{"ABC", "123"});

   public TestFrame() {
       this.add(jList);
       jList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);

   jList.setCellRenderer(new ListCellRenderer() {
       @Override
       public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
           for (int i : list.getSelectedIndices()) {
               if (index == i) {
                   JCheckBox checkBoxChecked = new JCheckBox(value.toString(), iconChecked);
                   return checkBoxChecked;
               }
           }

           JCheckBox checkBoxUnchecked = new JCheckBox(value.toString(), iconUnchecked);
           return checkBoxUnchecked;
       }
   });
   }}
   ```

Comment: Of course, since the toggle function of the checkbox isn't really used here, you can use other components to render the list cell in a similar way.

Comment: Thanks it worked, I had a new class which handled ListCellRenderer and was more complex than this, Your code way more simpler and easier to understand. Do you have any tips on how to make it stay checked till i press a button, then the values has to transfer to the jtable, as it stands now the custom checkboxes appear, but only gets checked if i press one column, I want multiple selections where I can check 3-4 daily goals and it should stay checked. The way it is now I can only press one daily goal, as soon as i hit the next the previous one gets unchecked... Any solutions?

Comment: @JavaGamer you can refer to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528344/jlist-deselect-when-clicking-an-already-selected-item for a detailed discussion.